# How to interpolate json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I'm using plotly to create chart and for which my data is in json string format.
here is the data

```
var data = [
 {
   "name ": "abc",
   "id ": 1,
   "sales": 205

 },
 {
   "name ": "abc",
   "id ": 1,
   "sales": 300

 },
 {
   "name ": "abc",
   "id ": 1,
   "sales": -1

 },
 {
   "name ": "abc",
   "id ": 1,
   "sales": -1

 },
 {
   "name ": "abc",
   "id ": 1,
   "sales": 800

 },
 {
   "name ": "abc",
   "id ": 1,
   "sales": 450

 },
 {
   "name ": "pqr",
   "id ": 2,
   "sales": 214

 },
 {
   "name ": "pqr",
   "id ": 2,
   "sales": 560

 },
 {
   "name ": "pqr",
   "id ": 2,
   "sales": 490

 },
 {
   "name ": "pqr",
   "id ": 2,
   "sales": -1

 },
 {
   "name ": "pqr",
   "id ": 2,
   "sales": 650
 }]
```

I have some missing values in **sales** column of data which is represented by `-1`. I'm trying to interpolate those missing data by calculating compound annual growth rate ([CAGR](http://www.investinganswers.com/financial-dictionary/ratio-analysis/compound-annual-growth-rate-cagr-1096)). so I'll determine first index of `-1` say `firstidx` within same `id` and last index of `-1` say `lastidx` within same `id` and calculate CAGR as per formula mentioned in link and fill those data in place of `-1` which is nothing but missing values. I tried with some dummy code in javascript but couldn't through.

> The formula for CAGR is:
>
> CAGR   =   ( EV / BV)1 / n - 1
>
> where:
>
> EV = Investment's ending value BV = Investment's beginning value n   =
>   Number of periods (months, years, etc.)

**dummy code**

```
function interpolate(jsString){
var firstidx = data.FirstIndexOf(data[sales]) - number(1) // subtracted 1 because to get the value for  beginning value to calculate CAGR
var lastidx = data.lastIndexOf(data[sales]) + number(1) // added 1 because to get the value for  ending value to calculate CAGR
var n = lastidx - (data.IndexOf(data[sales])
var cagr = ((lastidx/firstidx)^(1/n)-1) //formula of CAGR
}
```

Any suggestion on how that functionality can be achieved.

Thanks

Domnick

Comment: What shoult `data.IndexOf(data[sales])` do?

Comment: It's not clear how would you define your BV and EV

Comment: Not sure how CAGR can replace your -1 values, it's kind of AverageTotal of multiple values

Comment: @guijob the 'EV` and `BV` are nothing but `lastidx ` and `firstidx ` respectively.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly `-1` is just the representation of blank values  which needs to be replaced using CAGR calculation.

Comment: That's the point, replacing empty values with Average, but you are not getting proper Average

Comment: `not getting proper Average`?? but the same CAGR calculation returns correct values

Answer (score 0):

Just `find` the indices were the names equal, then take its value:

```
function fillSales(product, i, products) {
    // If sales already exists, stop here:
    if(product.sales !== -1) return;

    const BVi = products.findIndex(p => p.name === product.name);
    const BV = (products[BVi] || {}).sales || 0;

    const EVi = products.reduceRight((res, p, i) => res ? res : p.name === product.name ? i : null, null);
    const EV = (products[EVi] || {}).sales || 0;

    product.sales = (EV / BV) ** (1/ (EVi - BVi));
}
```

So one can do:

```
 data.forEach(fillSales);
```

Comment: If you could please elaborate your function.